# Query for dynamic OPENJSON query by passing key name

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I want to write a dynamic query for inserting a JSON array into records.

JSON is as below

```
{
list:[
     {id:1,name:"abc"}
    ,{id:2,name:"xyz"}
]
}
```

I want to pass a value that matches with attribute(key) of JSON that match with the table value (The shortname has these attribute values)

For example purpose, I kept only two attributes, but I have around 20 attributes which I will be inserting into a table as 20 separate records.
How do I make the JSON pick dynamically?

```
set @shortname = (select shortname from @table )
loop through @shortname

insert into @targettable (field1,field1)
select (select key from master table where id=**@shortname**),
        @shortname
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.List')
           WITH (**@shortname** nvarchar(max))jsonInput;
           
END
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz"}
]
}'

SELECT 
    tJson.[key] AS indexKey, tJson.[value] AS arrayValue, tJson.[type]  
    ,tList.k1
    ,tList.v1
    ,tList.t1
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement
    ) AS tList
```

**Note:** 
JavaScript/JSON is case-sensitive. 
So `'$.List'` and `'$.list'` is not the same.

If you want to get a list of lists, you do it the same way, just on the `'$'` object.

Now, for example, if you want to limit that to all occurences of name, you'd do it like this:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz"}
]
}'

SELECT 
    tJson.[key] AS indexKey, tJson.[value] AS arrayValue, tJson.[type]  
    ,tList.k1
    ,tList.v1
    ,tList.t1
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement
        WHERE tArrayElement.[key] = 'name'
    ) AS tList
```

The problem is, all your values will be in rows instead of columns, so you'd need to either join each name separately, or you'd need to pivot, which can't be done dynamically, unless you want to use dynamic sql.

Like so:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz"}
]
}'

SELECT 
    tJson.[key] AS indexKey, tJson.[value] AS arrayValue, tJson.[type]  
    ,tList.k1
    ,tList.v1
    ,tList.t1

    ,k2, v2, t2
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement
        WHERE tArrayElement.[key] = 'name'
    ) AS tList 



OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k2, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v2, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t2
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement
        WHERE tArrayElement.[key] = 'id'
    ) AS tList2
```

And with pivot like this:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz"}
]
}'

SELECT 
     [key], [value]
    ,MAX([id]) AS id 
    ,MAX([name]) AS name 
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement
    ) AS tList 
PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(tList.v1)  
    FOR tList.k1 IN ([id], [name])  
) AS tPivot 


GROUP BY [key], [value] 
;
```

Now you'd need "dynamic" sql to make the pivot columns "dynamic".

The list of names to pivot by, you can fetch dynamically, with:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz"}
]
}'

SELECT 
    QUOTENAME(tList.k1) AS k 
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement 
    ) AS tList 

GROUP BY tList.k1
```

And so you make it fully dynamic, like this:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(MAX)
SET @json = N'{
"list":[
 {"id":1,"name":"abc", "foo":"bar"}
,{"id":2,"name":"xyz", "bar":"foo"}
]
}'

DECLARE @pivotFields nvarchar(MAX) 
DECLARE @maxPivotFields nvarchar(MAX) 

SELECT 
    @pivotFields = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT 
            ', ' + QUOTENAME(tList.k1) AS [text()]
            --', MAX(' + QUOTENAME(tList.k1) + ')' AS [text()]
        FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

        OUTER APPLY 
            (
                SELECT  
                    tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
                    tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
                    tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
                FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement 
            ) AS tList 

        GROUP BY tList.k1 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')
    ,1,2, '') 
    


SELECT 
    @maxPivotFields = (
        SELECT 
            ', MAX(' + QUOTENAME(tList.k1) + ') AS ' 
            + QUOTENAME(tList.k1) AS [text()]
        FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.list') AS tJson 

        OUTER APPLY 
            (
                SELECT  
                    tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
                    tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
                    tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
                FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], '$') AS tArrayElement 
            ) AS tList 

        GROUP BY tList.k1 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')
    


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = N'SELECT 
     [key], [value]
    ' +  @maxPivotFields + N'

FROM OPENJSON (@json, ''$.list'') AS tJson 

OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  
            tArrayElement.[key] AS k1, 
            tArrayElement.[value] AS v1, 
            tArrayElement.[type] AS t1
        FROM OPENJSON(tJson.[value], ''$'') AS tArrayElement
    ) AS tList 
PIVOT  
(  
    MAX(tList.v1)  
    FOR tList.k1 IN (' + @PivotFields + N')  
) AS tPivot 

GROUP BY [key], [value] 
;  '

    
-- SELECT @PivotFields, @maxPivotFields
-- PRINT @sql


EXEC sp_executesql   
           @sql
          ,N'@json nvarchar(MAX)'
          ,@json = @json;
```